# After upgrade, I can't generate pdf letters for printing. How can I enable wkhtmlpdf to handle pdf conversion?

Tags: pdf, printing

Just upgraded CiviCRM. Running 4.7.29 on D7.56. Have installed wkhtmltopdf at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
I have placed exactly that file path into the settings in the admin for the "alternate" pdf generator. Doesn't seem to work. Get fatal error when I try to generate pdfs for printing. Here is the alert message:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_SelectValues::documentFormat() in /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommon.php on line 186`

Don't think wkhtmlpdf is executing. Is there a test to see if wkhtmlpdf is handling the conversion, as opposed to dompdf? Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message looks unrelated to whether wkhtmltopdf is being used. That method should exist and should be in CRM/Core/SelectValues.php at line 1077 (in 4.7.29)  Corrupted download?  Out of disk space?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have at 1077-1084:                                         
 public static function documentFormat() {
    return array(
      'pdf' => ts('Portable Document Format (.pdf)'),
      'docx' => ts('MS Word (.docx)'),
      'odt' => ts('Open Office (.odt)'),
      'html' => ts('Webpage (.html)'),
    );
  }

Comment: Is that code at 1077 what I should expect?

Comment: That is right - compare https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.29/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php#L1077  That is the function it is complaining about not finding.  Is there anything else not working?  What steps are you doing to attempt to generate the pdf?

Comment: Yes, we get other bad behavior when trying to print from civi. To produce the error above: We do a "find contributions" filtered by date, generate a list, select the contributions, select "thank you letters-email or print" under "actions". That last step produces the error. We do not get to the mail module "select template". If I go to the contact record and select "print or merge document" under actions, I get a white-screen-of-death pop-up. However, if I select "print summary" I get what I expect, it opens my system print dialog and displays a well-formatted document to print.

Comment: BTW: we have a non-production site that is a copy of the production site. We have not installed wkhtmltopdf on it. dompdf is giving us fits which is why we are trying wkhtmltopdf. On the test site, when I try to perform the same steps I get errors, but completely different in kind.

Comment: Just thinking out loud...is there a test to see if wkhtmltopdf is executing? FYI: I had tech support install wkhtmltopdf on the server. Did not do it myself. I can use ssh cli. I will try to see if I can at least locate the wkhtmltopdf file at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: John - Find me on chat.civicrm.org - aydun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to uninstall/reinstall sumfields! However, I had to manually delete row/drop tables (value_sumfields and custom_groups) in order to "clean install" sumfields. Still don't know why, but my instance was buggy. The usual uninstall/install procedure in the extensions manager didn't work for me. Talked to Jamie McClelland and he confirmed that I could/should manually make changes to the tables and then reinstall 3.1.1 of sumfields. NOTE: I had originally assumed that the problem had to do with wkhtmltopdf and so started down a bunny trail. For some reason upgrading from 4.7.22 to 4.7.29 AND having sumfields enabled AND using alternate pdf generator caused/revealed the problem on my instance. I will continue to investigate this, but I want to give a big shout out to Aidan at Squiffle and to Jamie at Progressive Tech Project for sticking with me.